# Error in connecting to multiple endpoints in react graphql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an existing graphql server from which I am consuming data. I am required now to connect to another 3rd party graphql from whom I have to consume data. I am not able to create another client for that. 
I am able to create separate components which can connect individually to the 3rd party service. But I do have many components which would be consuming from them. By creating individual components, it would get cumbersome for me to do so.

I don't want to create multiple components like this(below) to connect 3rd party service!

Is it possible to create another client and make request?

```
return (
  <Query query={gql`
            {
               my query here
            }

              `} client={customClient} >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {

      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
      let usersList = data.allPopulation;
      return (
        <div>
          <SelectList
            label='Patients Name'
            options={usersList}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
```